# Compute, up to isomorphism, all groups of order $21$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to solve this problem from my group theory course:

> Compute, up to isomorphism, all groups of order $21$

I've first considered the abelian case, whih gives me as Elemental Divisors $3$, $7$, so one group is
$$\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_7=\boxed{\mathbb{Z}_{21}}$$
After this, I don't know what to do. I have trouble with this kind of problems in general, where I'm asked to find all groups of certain order (The abelian case is easy to handle, I have trouble when the group is non-abelian). What is a general tip for solving this kind of problems? What is the solution in my example? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the concept of semidirect product?

Comment: @ArsenBerk Yes, but I have trouble understanding it and where it is possible. Then I guess one option is $\mathbb{Z}_3\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_7$ or something like that right?

Comment: @ArsenBerk Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my answer:

Given $|G|=21=3\cdot 7$ (product of two primes), and given that $3|(7-1)$, from my textbook I know that the only possible groups (up to isomorphism) are:

- $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_7\cong\mathbb{Z}_{21}$
- $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_3$

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun It's "Groups and Galois theory - course notes" from Alberto Elduque